# AWS API domain empty base mapping is not working

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway v1 `foo`.

This api gateway has a stage `bar`

I am trying to setup a domain name `baz.com` to access this stage.

When I create a new domain name with API mapping to `foo` (stage and path empty), I am able to access my api with `https://baz.com/bar/user/get`.

However, when I try to access my api with API mapping to `foo`, stage to `bar` and path empty, querying `https://baz.com/user/get` doesn't work (I am getting `Could not find matching action for /get and method POST`). Even weirder, setting path mapping to `a`, I am able to query my api : `https://baz.com/a/user/get`.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I tried to set path mapping to `/` but I get an error : `API Gateway V1 doesn't support the slash character (/) in base path mappings. To create a multi-level base path mapping, use API Gateway V2.`

With path set to `a` :

[image]

With empty path :

[image]

I am completly lost, it turns out my lambda do get call and return a 200 :

[image]

Yet it ends up being a 404

Comment: You are using the wrong domain name.

You should use the domain name that you created with the API mapping to foo, stage to bar and path empty.

The path mapping is only used if you want to map a path to a different path. For example, if you want to map /a to /b.

If you want to access your API with the path /user/get, you should use the domain name that you created with the API mapping to foo, stage to bar and path empty.

Comment: @LuckyOwl It seems that is what I'm trying to say. My settings for the domain in "API mapping" are API : `foo`, stage : `bar` and path : empty. And I am not able to access my api with `https://baz.com/user/get` :(

Comment: You should be able to access your API with the path /user/get using the domain name that you created with the API mapping to foo, stage to bar and path empty

Comment: I have added screen capture of postman and aws configuration @LuckyOwl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not related to API Gateway but to the library I used, `aws-lambda-routing`.

There was a bug regarding the use of custom domain name that is documented in the following issue : https://github.com/spring-media/aws-lambda-router/issues/27

A PR was made a year ago and the solution is now to set `removeBasePath` to `false`